# Changing 0s to get the maximum sequence of 1s

Tags: c++

I am trying to solve this problem about finding the index of 0 if c changed to 1 will make the longest sequence of 1s in a binary sequence.

There are many different ways for solving this problem. One by maintaining three variables of different positions of zeros. But it's not my algorithm, mine is the following. I would love if it would be optimized to work completely.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    freopen("input.txt", "r", stdin);
    freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);

    int n, temp = 0, count = 0, res = 0;
    bool found = true;

    cin >> n;
    int *a = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] == 1 || (a[i] == 0 && found == true) && a[i + 1] != 0) {
            count++;
            if (count >= temp) {
                temp = count;
                if (a[i] == 0) {
                    res = i;
                    found = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            count = 0;
            found = true;
        }
    }

    cout << res + 1;

    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```

The algorithm fails for this input:
10

0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1

It should output 8 rather than 2.

Comment: you should explain more on **your** algorithm.

Comment: "It's not optimized to work completely" is a euphemism I'm saving for the next time someone claims that my code has bugs.

Comment: `a[i + 1]` is a potential out-of-bounds access.

Comment: Basically, ir works on the idea of finding two zeros to determine sections. If you want a more lengthy explanation I can give it.

Comment: @Nap yes please describe more closely why it should ouput 8 for the given input. Where would you apply this kind of algorithm (e.g. is it useful in applied science?)

Comment: @HåkonHægland it should output 8 because if you flip 0 in 7th position (8 required for output since we add 1) you get the longest sequence of 1s.

Comment: @Nap So `001101` will have length 4 and index 5, and `0011001` will have length 3 and index 2 (or will it have index 5)?

Comment: But the longest sequence of 1s _will be_ if you flip bit 2. That'll be a length of 8 instead of 6. So without actually having looked at your algorithm, it seems like it works correctly. Surely, 0011111111 contains a longer 1-sequence than 0111111011, does it not?

Comment: @HåkonHægland Actually, the first one the answer should be 6 (5 as the index + 1), while the second one it should be 5 (4 + 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example for the solution:

```
#include <iostream> // cin, cout
#include <vector> // vector

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> a(n);
    for (auto& x : a)
        std::cin >> x;

    bool is_flipped = false; // Indicates whether we are currently testing a bit or not.
    int index = -1; // Index of the currently tested bit.
    int max_index = -1; // Index of the bit that gave us the longest sequence.
    int length = 0; // Length of the current sequence.
    int max_length = 0; // Length of the longest sequence.

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (a[i] == 0) {
            if (is_flipped) {
                is_flipped = false;
                length = -1;
                if (i + 1 < n && a[i + 1] == 1)
                    i = index;
            } else {
                is_flipped = true;
                index = i;
            }
        }
        ++length;
        if (length > max_length) {
            max_index = index;
            max_length = length;
        }
    }

    std::cout << max_index + 1 << '\n';
}
```

Be aware that `max_index` will be `-1` if the algorithm couldn't flip any bit (for example: a sequence full of `1`s).

---

In addition, I would like to call your attention to one detail: **Always check if `i + 1` is in the bounds of your array** because you don't want to access something that's out of it. Like this: `i + 1 < n && a[i + 1] != 0` where `n` is the size of your array. Other than that, I would advise you to use [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of the C-style array. It is a dynamic array with a lots of nice features.

Comment: Actually it doesn't solve the problem, try out this case;


1 1 0 1

Comment: You are right. I edited my answer with my own algorithm and provided a C++ implementation for it.